# Move Bottom Tabs(rn-viewpager) from bottom to top when any tab is clicked

Tags: react-native, tabs, viewpagerindicator

I am using "rn-viewpager" library in my react native project. Initially i want to show tabs at bottom of page but when user select any one of then they should move to top of the page.[image: Image 1 where tabs are at bottom Initially]  [image: Image 2 where second tab is selected]

```
   <View style={Container.homeScreen_container}>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor:'#008fda',flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                {/ <DrawerHeader title="ABC"/> /}
                <View style={Container.drawer_header_container}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.openDrawer}>
                        {/ <Image style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginTop: 10, height: 35, width: 35 }} source={require('../img/ic_menu.png')}></Image> /}
                        <Image style={{ marginLeft: 15, marginTop: 20,height: 24, width: 24 }} source={require('../img/ic_menu.png')}></Image>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={{ marginTop: 16, marginLeft: 30, color: 'white', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Metlife</Text>
                </View>
                <Image style={{ marginRight:10, justifyContent: 'flex-end',marginTop: 14, height: 30, width: 30 }} source={require('../img/ic_notifications_white_24dp.png')}/>
                <Image style={{ marginRight:10, justifyContent: 'flex-end',marginTop: 14, height: 30, width: 30 }} source={require('../img/ic_search_white_24dp.png')}/>
            </View>
            <IndicatorViewPager
                style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20, backgroundColor: 'white' }}
                //  indicator = { this._renderTitleIndicator() }
                indicator={this._renderTabIndicator()}
            >
                <View><ToDoScreen propsAre = {this.props}/></View>
                <View><TabScreen2 /></View>
                <View><TabScreen3 /></View>
            </IndicatorViewPager>

            {/* <MaterialTabs
                items={['TO DO', 'WOULD YOU LIKE TO DO', 'DISCOVER']}
                selectedIndex={this.state.selectedTabNo}
                onChange={this.setTab.bind(this)}
                barColor="#018ED6"
                indicatorColor="#fffe94"
                activeTextColor="white"
            />
            {this.state.DynamicaView} */}
        </View >
```